# Angular 2 pushing items to array using SharedService to update UI

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I'm trying to update a cart count when you add an item to the basket, the only way I could think is save the items using `localStorage` however I want to update the UI as soon as a user add an item.

So I thought I can create a `SharedService` and push the items there instead, but how do I retrieve the `array` of items from that service to update the UI when user add an item?

SharedService so far --

```
export class SharedServiceService {
public itemArr: any = [];
  constructor() { }

  itemCollection(item) {
    this.itemArr.push(item);
    console.log(this.itemArr);
  }
}
```

My AddToBasket component function --

```
addToBasket(itemCode) {
  this.sharedServiceService.itemCollection(itemCode);
}
```

I want to retrieve the `array` of items from my `app.component`, thought it'd be as simple as this but ofc its not as this `this.basketCount` is returning `[]` empty array. I want to show is the `array` length `(10) Items`.

```
ngOnInit() {
 // console.log(this.sharedServiceService.itemArr);
    this.basketCount = this.sharedServiceService.itemArr;
  }
```

[Plnkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1ver8v5CXHn7XJ3PHxR3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is as simple as getting the array. It may not be working in your case, because you are doing it in the ngOnInit(), which runs only once when the array is still empty. But if you put it somewhere else, for example in your app component template, you will see how it updates:

```
<div>
  <h2>Basket Count ({{sharedService.itemArr.length}}) show count</h2>
  <app-basket></app-basket>
  {{ sharedService.itemArr | json }}
</div>
```

To make it more readable, you may also use computed properties:

```
private get basketCount():number { 
  return this.sharedService.itemArr.length; 
}

private get basket {
  return this.sharedService.itemArr;
}
```

Then you simply interpolate the computed property:

```
<div>
  <h2>Basket Count ({{ basketCount }}), or ({{ basket.length }}) show count</h2>
  <app-basket></app-basket>
  {{ basket | json }}
</div>
```

Comment: Glad it worked, also if you are going to use the count a lot, you may want to create a computed property: `private get basketCount():number { return this.sharedService.itemArr.length; }` and then directly interpolate `{{ basketCount }}`. Same goes for the array.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to use the computed properties.